# How to find nodes in a link-cut tree?

Tags: data-structures

All link-cut tree operations are described assuming that we already have a node we want to perform the operation on, but how do I have to store the tree to be able to get to that node in the first place?

I can't just store the root of the abstract tree, because link-cut trees don't support descendant search so most of the nodes in the tree will be lost.

I had an idea to store roots of every solid tree (splay tree) in a vector, but there's another problem: solid trees are constantly changing their structure, which means I will have to recalculate roots of each tree after performing any operation, which is complicated, slow, and definitely is not correct.

So what is the correct way to store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link/cut tree has one tree node for each node in the graph it’s representing. You therefore typically address this in one of two ways:

1. When you create the link/cut tree nodes for each graph node, make a hash table mapping each graph node to its link/cut tree node. This gives you (expected) O(1) access to the link/cut tree nodes you need.
2. Use an ***intrusive data structure*** by having each graph node also have all the fields needed for the link/cut tree. In that sense, each graph node literally becomes a node in the link/cut tree, so once you have the graph node you want, you also have the link/cut tree node.